# Jboss 7 Destroy Singleton EJB

Tags: java, jboss7.x, scheduling, ejb-3.1

```
@Startup
@Singleton
@AccessTimeout(value = 0)
public class MyEJB {
@Schedule(dayOfWeek = "*", hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/20", year = "*", persistent = false, info = "MyEjb Job.................")
    @AccessTimeout(value = 0)
    public void execute() {
        try {
            lgg.debug("starting...........");
            Thread.sleep(35000);
            lgg.debug("ending.............");
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        }
}
```

I have the following code. I want to stop(destroy) current EJB working after 20 second and start another Singltone EJB instance. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  You cannot safely force a thread to stop in the JVM, and there is no mechanism in EJB to interrupt a thread.  The best you can do is cooperatively interrupt: call another method on the singleton to notify it to wake up (that is, change the Thread.sleep to something else like a CountDownLatch).  Note, you'll need to change the default `@Lock` or `@ConcurrencyManagement` to allow the bean to be reentrant.